# Why python only printing the last key from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I was trying the make a function in python and using a for loop to iterate all keys or values from a dictionary and I was trying to assign a global variable inside the function so I can print the keys outside the function but it was only printing the last key:

```
ships = {
'playerShip1' : cv.imread(r'C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\desktopFolders\\pyexample\\seafightShip.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED),
'playership2' : cv.imread(r'C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\desktopFolders\\pyexample\\seafightCroped.jpg', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
}

def att():
global key
for key in ships:
    global shipLoc
    shipLoc = key
    #it works okay here     
    #print(key) 

att()
#quit()

#but it only prints the last key here
print(key)
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

It only prints the last key because your `print()` call is outside of the `for` loop that iterates over the keys. By the time the program gets to your uncommented `print()`, the value of `key` is the final value it was assigned inside the loop. To print all values of `key`, uncomment the `print(key)` call inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Every iteration of the for loop `key` receives a new value. Once the for loop ended, only the last value of `key` is assigned to the variable `key`.